# is there any way i can set the height of image in percent(100%) in a bootstrap column class?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I am creating 2 columns in container-fluid class and I am inserting an image in the first column with the height and width of 100% the width is working but height is not working

```
bootcamp.html:~

<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row ">
<div class="col-lg-6 padding-0"><img src="assets/images/2.jpeg" >
</div>
<div class="col-lg-6 padding-0 ">there should be a form </div>
</div>
</div>

bootcamp.css:~

.container-fluid{
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
padding-left: 0px;
padding-right: 0px;
}
.row{
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
margin: 0px;
}
.row .col-lg-6 img {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
.padding-0{
padding-right:0;
padding-left:0;
}
```

Comment: try 100vh instead of 100 %

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want your container and images in it to be 100% height of screen (viewport), then use `height:100vh` as Amit said.

But if you want 100% height of parent div (`col-lg-6` in your case) then you could make parent's `position: relative; height: whatever-you-like` and image's `position: absolute; height: 100%; width: 100%;` .